# Control Click in chrome breaks the frame of my website

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frame

I have a website that has two frames. The left one is the main menu and the one to the right displays the content. However, when someone uses **control+click** in Chrome the new tab displays the iframe page (i.e. the menu is gone).

Is it possible for a content page to detect that it's being displayed outside the iframe and do a redirect or some other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "a" tag. Use any other tag instead. Implement it by javascript such as addEventListener for changing the content of right frame

or you can hold on all links like below

```

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    // {Boolean} e.ctrlKey - if user press ctrlKey when clicking
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.target.tagName === "A"){
        e.preventDefault();
        // manually handle your content changing
        // below is a simple example, your should modify it under your logic
        document.querySelector("your-right-iframe").src = e.target..getAttribute("href")
    }
// the true means you are in capture mode
},true)
```

```

Comment: So you propose that I should modify a huge website (actually a complex system) by replacing all a tags? Ain't there any other way? I suppose there should be something simpler than that. Maybe an automatic way via jquery to do what you propose? It's actually non viable for us to replace all a tags in the website manually.

Comment: Ashe, thanks, that's a great solution. BUT, I'm not looking to prevent the behaviour of opening a new tab, instead I want the tab to be displayed INSIDE the iframe, keeping the original look of the website. Can I achieve this with some modification to your code?

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson  I actually well knew what you want, This solution is fully matched your requirement.  Change the src of iframe to be the href which user clicked. It already done. So I think it's just what you say "displayed INSIDE the iframe"

Comment: I want the new tab to be opened. With your solution it's not, sorry

Comment: Got it.  open itself  with query. I suppose your html file was called foo.html.
window.open('foo.html?src=xyz.com/abc/def.something')

Comment: Then, add a function to onload for receiving the query. and change the src of iframe